# MS Graph SendMail with attachment

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, sendmail, attachment

I have problem sending an email with an attachment. Without attachment it works.
If I use the same function and add an attachment to the message I get the following error message:

> **Code: ErrorRequiredPropertyMissing Message: Required property is missing. ClientRequestId: 2af....**

I am using `MS Graph v4.0.30319`

```
public static async Task<String> SendMyMailAsync()
{
    try
    {
        var FromSender = new Microsoft.Graph.Recipient()
        {
            EmailAddress = new Microsoft.Graph.EmailAddress
            {
                Address = "EarlyBird@mail.com"
            }
        };
        byte[] contentBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\me\Desktop\Test.pdf");
        String bs64 = Convert.ToBase64String(contentBytes);
        var attachment = new FileAttachment
        {

            AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
            {
                {"@odata.type","#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment"}
            },
            //ODataType = "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
            ContentType = "application/pdf",
            Name = "Test.pdf",
            ContentBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(bs64),
            IsInline = false,
            Size = bs64.Length,
            ContentId = "TestMail",
            LastModifiedDateTime = DateTime.Now,
            Id = "HSDJHEWuDSjfkkfGt",
        };


        Microsoft.Graph.Message message = new Microsoft.Graph.Message
        {
            Sender = FromSender,
            From = FromSender,
            Subject = "Mail no1",
            Importance = Microsoft.Graph.Importance.Normal,
            Body = new Microsoft.Graph.ItemBody
            {
                ContentType = Microsoft.Graph.BodyType.Html,
                Content = "Hello World",
            },
            ToRecipients = new List<Microsoft.Graph.Recipient>()
            {
                new Microsoft.Graph.Recipient
                {
                    EmailAddress = new Microsoft.Graph.EmailAddress
                    {
                        Address = "EarlyBird@MailNo2.com"
                    }
                }
            },
            Attachments = new MessageAttachmentsCollectionPage(),
        };

        // -- If I comment this out I can send the mail without error but without attachment----
        message.Attachments.Add(attachment);
        message.HasAttachments = true;
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------


        var request = graphClient.Me.SendMail(message, true); 
        // Messages[message.Id].Send();// SendMail(message, null);
        await request.Request().PostAsync();

        return "Mail send OK";
    }
    catch (ServiceException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Error getting events: {ex.Message}");
        return "Send mail error";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The below code works perfectly fine for me

```
        public static async Task<String> SendMyMailAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                var FromSender = new Microsoft.Graph.Recipient()
                {
                    EmailAddress = new Microsoft.Graph.EmailAddress
                    {
                        Address = "Shiva@nishantsingh.live"
                    }
                };
                byte[] contentBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\Shiva\Desktop\sample.pdf");
                String bs64 = Convert.ToBase64String(contentBytes);
                var attachment = new FileAttachment
                {

                    AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
                    {
                        {"@odata.type","#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment"}
                    },
                    ContentType = "application/pdf",
                    Name = "Test.pdf",
                    ContentBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(bs64),
                    IsInline = false,
                    Size = bs64.Length,
                    ContentId = "TestMail",
                    LastModifiedDateTime = DateTime.Now,
                    Id = "HSDJHEWuDSjfkkfGt",
                };


                Microsoft.Graph.Message message = new Microsoft.Graph.Message
                {
                    Sender = FromSender,
                    From = FromSender,
                    Subject = "Mail no1",
                    Importance = Microsoft.Graph.Importance.Normal,
                    Body = new Microsoft.Graph.ItemBody
                    {
                        ContentType = Microsoft.Graph.BodyType.Html,
                        Content = "Hello World",
                    },
                    ToRecipients = new List<Microsoft.Graph.Recipient>()
                    {
                        new Microsoft.Graph.Recipient
                        {
                            EmailAddress = new Microsoft.Graph.EmailAddress
                            {
                                Address = "Shiva@nishantsingh.live"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    Attachments = new MessageAttachmentsCollectionPage(),
                };
                message.HasAttachments = true;
                message.Attachments.Add(attachment);
                var request = graphClient.Me.SendMail(message, true);
                await request.Request().PostAsync();

                return "Mail send OK";
            }
            catch (ServiceException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error getting events: {ex.Message}");
                return "Send mail error";
            }
        }
```

You need to make sure that you have the PDF file path correctly specified and the fromSender variable will obviously be yours as you are calling `me/sendMail`. If you want to send mail from other user's mailbox then you need to have client credential flow setup so that it can give you an App-only token which should have required permissions and you need to change the call something like this `var request = graphClient.Users["userid/UPN"].SendMail(message, true);`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
When I debug the program I see that the PDF file is loaded.
When I send the mail without attachment it works for me too.
Only when I add the attachment in the mail I get the following error message:
***Code: ErrorRequiredPropertyMissing Message: Required property is missing. ClientRequestId: 2af...***

It does not seem to be a permission problem.
The PDF file is also loaded correctly.
Which MS Graph version do you use?
@shiva-keshav-varma

Answer (score 1):

I have just updated the MS Graph preview version from
4.0.0-preview.1
to
4.0.0-preview.2
Now everything works as expected
I think it was a bug in preview.1

Comment: Great to hear. Always i would suggest you to make use of the latest Graph API versions, as most of the reported the issues are fixed.

Comment: You can select your own answer as correct. You get points and it closes out the question as complete.